# Why does the method runtimeClass of ClassTag return a wildcard class?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

The `runtimeClass` method of a `ClassTag[T]` returns a `Class[_]`. I would expect it to return a `Class[T]`, since we know the `ClassTag[T]` represents the (runtime) class of `T`.

Why does it return "any" `Class`? Is there a fundamental reason for that?

Comment: Beats me. I haven't managed to create a `ClassTag[T]` whose `runtimeClass` would be different from `classOf[T]`, and the latter returns a `Class[T]`. Maybe this is a historical artifact of the migration from `Manifest`s to `ClassTag`s? I can believe manifests would have had problems guaranteeing the exact type. Maybe this is *still* an artifact of the "interop" with manifests. I think only a few people on scala-internals can answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene Burmako (via scala-internals), we have the following counter example:

```
scala> classTag[Array[_]].runtimeClass
res0: Class[_] = class java.lang.Object
```

`Array[T]` does not erase its type parameter at runtime (unlike other generics). Therefore, it is not possible to represent a wildchard `Array` type with an accurate `Class`. Hence the fallback to `Object`.

It is interesting to see, that the same argument applies to the typing of `classOf` (as @sjrd mentions):

```
scala> classOf[Array[_]]
res0: Class[Array[_]] = class java.lang.Object
```

Where arguably `class java.lang.Object` is not of type `Class[Array[_]]`.

[Post on scala-internals](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/UlBrt6RLppc)