# Get fully qualified class object from Scala generic parameters

Tags: scala

I am trying to create an interface where I need, at runtime, the class object corresponding to a generic class.

The following code shows my problem.

```
package com.example

import java.util.function.Consumer
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import java.util.Collection


trait DomObj:
  def foo(): Unit

trait DomObjA extends DomObj:
  def bar(): Unit


/** This is an external, Java API that I cannot change */
trait Store:
  def subscribe[T <: DomObj](cls: Class[T], cons: Consumer[Collection[T]]) = ???

/** This is the class I am trying to write */
object Client:
  val store: Store = ???
  def sub1[T <: DomObj](cons: Consumer[Collection[T]])(using classTag: ClassTag[T]): Unit =
    store.subscribe(classTag.runtimeClass, cons)
  def sub2[T <: DomObj](cons: Consumer[Collection[T]])(using classTag: ClassTag[T]): Unit =
    val cls: Class[T]  = classTag.runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[DomObj])
    store.subscribe(cls, cons)
  def sub3[T <: DomObj](cons: Consumer[Collection[T]])(using classTag: ClassTag[T]): Unit =
    val cls: Class[T] = classTag.runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[T])
    store.subscribe(cls, cons)
  def subSad[T <: DomObj](cls: Class[T], cons: Consumer[Collection[T]]): Unit =
    store.subscribe(cls, cons)

  def run(): Unit =
    val cons: Consumer[Collection[DomObjA]] = ???
    sub1(cons)
    sub2(cons)
    sub3(cons)
    subSad(classOf[DomObjA], cons)
```

`subSad` works, but I would like to avoid needing to explicitly specify the class.  This seems reasonable since the compiler knows the class and should be able to pass it as an implicit argument.  In fact, that appears to be the purpose of the `ClassTag` class.

However, none of the other attempts compiles.

*sub1*

```
[error] 30 |    store.subscribe(classTag.runtimeClass, cons)
[error]    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |  Found:    Class[?]
[error]    |  Required: Class[T]
[error]    |
[error]    |  where:    T is a type in method sub1 with bounds <: com.example.DomObj
```

*sub2*

```
[error] 32 |    val cls: Class[T]  = classTag.runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[DomObj])
[error]    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |  Found:    Class[? <: com.example.DomObj]
[error]    |  Required: Class[T]
[error]    |
[error]    |  where:    T is a type in method sub2 with bounds <: com.example.DomObj
```

*sub3*

```
[error] 35 |    val cls: Class[T] = classTag.runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[T])
[error]    |                                                                 ^
[error]    |  T is not a class type
[error]    |
[error]    |  where:    T is a type in method sub3 with bounds <: com.example.DomObj
```

It appears that in Scala 2, `TypeTag` probably did what I wanted, but that does not appear to exist in Scala 3.
Is there a way to make this work, or do I just need to use `subSad`?

This does compile:

```
  def sub4[T <: DomObj](cons: Consumer[Collection[T]])(using classTag: ClassTag[T]): Unit =
    val cls: Class[T] = classTag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
    store.subscribe(cls, cons)
```

although it uses `asInstanceOf` which is often a code smell.  It is just putting type parameters back on which we know are correct.

Comment: The `cast` is fine and is the solution you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast you mention is because the runtime class doesn't necessarily correspond to the Scala type. The `T` in `ClassTag[T]` is the Scala type, while the `U` in `Class[U]` is the erased Java-side class. While these two types usually coincide (modulo erasure of generic parameters), there are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467291/why-does-the-method-runtimeclass-of-classtag-return-a-wildcard-class) where they do not.

So casting the `Class[_]` to a `Class[T]` is fair game. It's an unchecked cast, but unchecked casts on `Class[_]` are not uncommon, even in the Java world. While I certainly respect your caution on `asInstanceOf`, it's pretty okay in this case.

Comment: If I was writing Java, I would cast and document why it's fine.  It feels like Scala has a better generics system, so I was hoping to be able to avoid the cast.